# What is the Best Way to See if Vectors are Equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Maybe this is a stupid question, but when I started to think about it I started to feel rather unsure. The question is what is the best way to see if vectors, or more specifically eigenvectors are equal? I want to compare two different methods that generates eigenvalues and eigenvectors and I want to show that the eigenvectors I obtained are more or less equal. I know I can compare the norm of the vectors and see if they are equal to each other, but is this *really* saying that they are equal? They have a direction too! My eigenvectors contains many elements so I can't really put them next to each other and say "Look! They are equal!". What is the best way to tell if two eigenvectors are equal?

Comment: Do you mean numerically or in hand calculations? Numerically equality testing is essentially impossible: you really only have "equality" up to a tolerance, which is usually at least 10 machine epsilons and often more like 10000 machine epsilons. There is also a problem of possibly choosing different representatives of the same eigenspace. You can fix this by normalizing the two vectors in the same fashion: for instance you could normalize them both so that their first components are both $1$. But if you have a multidimensional eigenspace for one eigenvalue, this still won't be enough.

Comment: Eigenvectors don't need to be equal.  They only belong to the same linear subspace (eigenspace).  What counts for an eigenvector it's only its direction, not its magnitude

Comment: You are confused. Two vectors, whether eigenvectors of something or not, are just equal if they are identical, and different when they are not identical. If you want to know whether two purported _bases of eigenvectors_ are compatible (that is they can indeed be such bases for the same linear operator) than that is a **different** question, and you should **reformulate** to say this (or whatever else you mean to ask); use the 'edit' button to do so. If correctly computed, then two bases of eigenvectors are _always_ compatible, but maybe you want to detect errors in computing one of the bases?

Answer (score 5):

You could compute the dot product of the two vectors, and if they are parallel (same direction) their dot product will be equal to the product of their individual norms. Then you can check norms and see if *they* are equal (same magnitudes).

Comment: Numerically, comparing the dot product with the product of the norms is a **very bad** way of testing parallelism. It is essentially testing whether an angle$~\alpha$ is a multiple of $\pi$ by checking whether $|\cos\alpha|=1$, which is numerically very unstable. A better way is to test all $2\times 2$ matrices of corresponding coordinates of being (nearly) zero. But in any case this is not what the question is asking (admittedly it is not clear what it _is_ asking); nothing in the question says that eigenspaces are of dimension$~1$, so one has to be able to compare spans of $>1$ vectors.

Answer (score 3):

Two vectors are equal if and only if all its components are equal.

So (1,2,3) is equal to (1,2,3). But (1,2,3) is not
equal to (1, 40, 3) as the 2nd components are different.

Comment: This answer may be a bit misleading, since the OP referred to eigenvectors specifically. While $(1, 2, 3)$ and $(2, 4, 6)$ may not be equal, they would be equivalent, as eigenvectors.

Comment: Even worse, the pair of eigenvectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ with the same eigenvalue, is equivalent to the pair of eigenvectors $(1,1,0)$ $(1,2,0)$, since they're bases for the same space.

Comment: I was talking about vectors in general. Maybe the OP meant something more specific.

Comment: This perfectly answers the actual question that was posed. Clearly OP is just confused and wanted to ask something different, but that should be handled in comments to the question, not to answers.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do it is by taking the component-wise difference between the vectors and then checking that the resulting vector is equal to the $0$ vector.

This method makes it easier to "see" the vectors are the same. For example it is much easier to confirm $$(0,0,12390330)\ne\vec{0}$$
rather than $$(18921049890,128433,352983620)\ne(18921049890,128433,340593290)$$

Comment: As another commenter put it: "This answer may be a bit misleading, since the OP referred to eigenvectors specifically. While (1,2,3) and (2,4,6) may not be equal, they would be equivalent, as eigenvectors. "

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio Well, the OP asks if two vectors are equal and then states checking equivalence of norm. It seems the OP is looking for when vectors are actually equal, never mind the fact that they are also eigenvectors (still, in my opinion danimal's answer is the best given here and it works in both cases).

Answer (score 1):

The norm will not tell you much, because if $v$ is an eigenvector, so is any multiple of $v$.

What you can do is to first normalise all your vectors to the same length. Then you can check the norm of the difference of two vectors.
As two vectors are equal if and only if their difference is $0$, and the norm of a vector is $0$ if and only if the vector is $0$.

If you have degenerate eigenvalues, then the corresponding eigenvectors will span a linear subspace. Then you need to check if the subspaces spanned by the eigenvectors found using the two different methods are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Peter's answer above, we must check that each component is equal to its equivalent in the other vector. If your vectors are algebraic not numeric then if one change of variables, re-parametrization or other transformation will take all elements in one vector to the other, then they may be seen as equal or related under the given transformation.